# Не работают breakpoint в wcf

Tags: c#, отладка, wcf

Ставлю brekpoint в файле wcf-сервиса, после запуска отладки вылезает "no symbols have been loaded". Тот же проект на другом компьютере нормально отрабатывает brekpoint. VS 2017, переустановка не помогла.

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в IIS Express, при Debuge надо делать attach к процессу IIS. Автоматически на моем компьютере этого не происходит. Как исправить не знаю.